# How can I convert a Beast Boost http request to a string

Tags: c++, boost, httprequest

I did a web server with Beast Boost C++, and I want to convert a `boost::beast::http::request` into a simple `string`

I tried to print the request in the console by doing

```
std::cout << req << std::endl;
```

and it worked. But I can't find any function in the documentation to get the entire request as a string.

I also tried to use a `std::ostringstream` by doing this:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << req;
std::string request_as_string = oss.str();
```

but I got the exception : `Microsoft C++ : std::out_of_range`

Comment: Put it in a [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) if you want a string instead of console output.

Comment: I tried that as well but it didn't worked too I got an exception.

Comment: What exception did you get? How `ostringstream` was used?

Comment: I did this : `std::ostringstream oss; oss << req; std::string request_as_string = oss.str();` and I got the exception : `Microsoft C++ : std::out_of_range ` with visual studio

Comment: That belongs in your question. What you tried, what didn't work and why. And an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so people can try for themselves without first guessing what you were doing.

Comment: I tried it right after you suggested me to do that so I didn't put it in the question. I'll do it right now